# Rails "/blog" path uninitialized constant Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to setup a rails blog at the "website.com/blog" url

I already have my models and controller setup to work to where going to

```
website.com/posts
```

Gives me all my posts and going to

```
website.com/posts/1/
```

Shows me that post, etc, etc. What I want to happen is that when I go to

```
website.com/blog/
```

I should see the posts index (and the original URL should no longer work). Similarly I want to go to

```
website.com/blog/posts/1/
```

To see that post and so on and so forth.

Right now this is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :blog do 
    resources :posts do 
      resources :comments
    end
  end 
  get "/blog", to: "posts#index"
end
```

When I go to "/blog/" I get a Routing Error saying "uninitialized constant Blog". Do I need to create a blog model and controller and migrate to complete this? I'd rather not since it's really just running the posts requests from that new URL. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I ended up finding the answer to my own question here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Using this seems to work just fine:

```
scope '/blog' do
    resources :posts do 
        resources :comments
    end
end 
get "/blog", to: "posts#index"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

As usual the solution was incredibly simple and made me feel like an idiot for not knowing what to do immediately:

```
scope '/blog' do
    resources :posts do 
        resources :comments
    end
end 
get "/blog", to: "posts#index"
```